# Does $\Pi_{i=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{R}$ have same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

This is true if we take the product of $\mathbb{R}$ with itself finitely many times, so I'm wondering if this is true for a countable product as well. The argument that I know for finite products, taking elements from particular positions of the binary expansion and forming numbers with these binary expansions, will not generalise to the countable case.

Comment: You can still take elements from particular positions in the binary expansion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The fastest way to see this is to observe that $\mathfrak{c} = 2^{ \aleph_0}$, so

$$ \mathfrak{c}^{\aleph_0} = (2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_0 \times \aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_0} = \mathfrak{c}. $$